# Delay EurekaClient startup in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Docs says that Eureka client can be integrated into Spring Application very simply, just add one annotation to your configuration class and several properties into your `application.properties`. But says nothing about manual startup/shutdown of client. I want to customize behaviour of that client (or delay its init, because (wow!) entire logic lays in [client's constructor](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/c111d08aee22178d1b300565baa4651e2924fdbf/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/discovery/DiscoveryClient.java#L324)): instead of background registration via Spring Boot's auto-configuration, client must register in Eureka server **when application (with Eureka client) itself gets initialized**, and only after that application will be able to gather metadata, put it to Eureka client's `metadataMap` and then start registration process in Eureka server. Of course, I can take `ApplicationInfoManager` instance and call [`registerAppMetadata`](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/c111d08aee22178d1b300565baa4651e2924fdbf/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/appinfo/ApplicationInfoManager.java#L156), but what do if dependant application (also registered in the server) requires that applications must register with required metadata?

Answer (score 0):

you could configure a health page and point the health check to it - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_status_page_and_health_indicator